# Scripting is not following the order?

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool

I have a script that has several lines and include 3 arcpy functions such as copy features, make xy layer event, and apply symbology. Right below those tools I am trying to use the arcpy.mapping to create a mxd file with the new layer and export as JPEG. However, when I do that it seems the script doesn't follow its order and the output (the mxd file and the jpeg) don't have the new layer, which was created and analyzed during the script.
*obs: I am trying with the script tool and it doesn't work, when I try just putting the script in the ArcMap python window, it works perfectly fine.

I am having problem on this part:

```
import csv
import os
import string
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "E:/Alex"
#variables
inp = arcpy.GetparameterAsText(0)
output = arcpy.GetparameterAsText(1)
#directories
outfile = "pathname"
jpeg = "pathname"
finalmap = "pathname"
    #csv reader
with open(inp, "r") as csvData:
    reader = csv.reader(csvData, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
#csv writer
    with open(outfile, "wb") as csvWriter:
        writer = csv.writer(csvWriter, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
try:
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
    outlayer = "Event_Layer"
    dataset = "examplelayer"
#Getting coordinate system from another layer
    spatialreference = "GEOGCS['GCS_North_American_1983',DATUM['D_North_American_1983',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]];-400 -400 11258999068426.2;-100000 10000;-100000 10000;8.98315284119521E-09;0.001;0.001;IsHighPrecision"


    arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(outfile,"lon","lat",outlayer,spatialreference,"")
 except Exception as err:
    print (err.args[0])


#Copying Features
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(outlayer,output)
#Map Layout 
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT") 
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "")[0] 
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, lyr, "TOP")
    arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(lyr, dataset) 
arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, jpeg, "PAGE_LAYOUT")`
mxd.saveACopy(finalmap)
del mxd, outlayer
```

Comment: If you created a layer prior to this code, then the code you have written is only dealing with layers already placed inside of your map and not that layer you built, since the lyr variable is only dealing with layers listed from the mxd.  You need to provide all of the code that creates the layer you are creating an analyzing.  Also, is this supposed to run as a tool script or as a purely standalone Python script run directly from Idle?

Comment: I am running as a tool script and I updated the code so you can understand better. Basically, I am creating that output and I want it to be in the jpeg and the mxd file.

Comment: Are you using the following line in the script? If so, change the keyword to the mxd path. mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

Comment: It didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Got it,

```
#Setting map layout
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "")[0]
addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(output)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer, "TOP")
#Set symbology
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[0]
arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(lyr, dataset)
mxd.saveACopy(finalmap)
arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, jpeg)
```

Answer (score 0):

This from the ESRI Help
 *The second technique is to use the CURRENT keyword as an input parameter to the MapDocument function. This technique only works from within an ArcMap application because the MapDocument object references the map document that is currently loaded into the ArcMap application. Using CURRENT is very helpful when quickly testing and learning the scripting capabilities and command syntax within the Python window. You may start off learning the syntax in the Python window, then start pasting those lines of code into a more permanent script saved to disk.* 
Try hard coding the path to the MXD.

Comment: The problem is not the way I am referring the mxd file. The problem is the output is not coming to the jpeg or mxd file. What I think is the script run the entire code and in this case to create the new map document it had to wait for the output load in the table of contents, so it could be exported with the map. I don't know the difference between the Python window and a script tool, but I know that in the python window it works because the script run step by step. For example, it create the output first and you can see each tool running also the time of success is shown.

Comment: arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, lyr, "TOP") should be arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, output, "TOP") maybe.